# Check if Geolocation is off in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, geolocation

I've got this code in my AIR app:

```
if (Geolocation.isSupported){
var my_geo:Geolocation = new Geolocation();
my_geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, onGeoUpdate);
}else{
    trace("Geolocation is not supported");
}
```

But how to check if the GPS is simply off ?

I would like something like :

```
if (Geolocation.isSupported){
var my_geo:Geolocation = new Geolocation();
my_geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, onGeoUpdate);
}
if Geolocation.isOff){
trace("Your GPS is off");
}
```

Thank you for your help
    else{
        trace("Geolocation is not supported");
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Geolocation.muted".

```
if (Geolocation.isSupported){
    var my_geo:Geolocation = new Geolocation();
    if (my_geo.muted){
        trace("Your GPS is off");
    }
    my_geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, onGeoUpdate);
}else{
    trace("Geolocation is not supported");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if the Geolocation [muted](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sensors/Geolocation.html) property is true or false to determine if access to the geolocation services are available (could be turned off or the user  could have denied access to the application)

i.e:

```
if (my_geo.muted) { }
```

If muted is false (thus it is on), then add an event handler to track if it gets turned off (and thus muted becomes true) during your application's use of the geo services so your application can notify user, or whatever you need to do if geo services are not available.

i.e.

```
if (!my_geo.muted) { 
   // start listening for geo updates
   my_geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, onGeoUpdate); 
}
// Listen for changes in the status of the geo service
my_geo.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, yourGEOServiceUpdateHandler);

    public function yourGEOServiceUpdateHandler(event:StatusEvent):void 
    { 
        if (my_geo.muted)
            my_geo.removeEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, onGeoUpdate);
        else
            my_geo.addEventListener(GeolocationEvent.UPDATE, onGeoUpdate);
    }
```